# Merge Merging GridView Header Columns Multiple Headers ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

```
protected void GrdLeaveMaster_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow HeaderGridRow =
        new GridViewRow(2, 2, DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow,
        DataControlRowState.Insert);
        TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "PaidLeave";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        HeaderCell = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell.Text = "accumulated";
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

        GrdLeaveMaster.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
    }
}
```

I want  header does not show in first column it shows on second column

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Also format your question and don't confuese tags and title.

Comment: i want paidleave shift in second column

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge Merger header columns in gridview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191195/merge-merger-header-columns-in-gridview)

Comment: Please refer to a possible solution [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9333714/1060656](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9333714/1060656)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
HeaderCell.Text = "";
HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 1;
HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
HeaderCell.Text = "PaidLeave";
HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 1;
HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
```

hope it helps

Comment: It just appends another empty column before.hope it helps

Comment: If it works then accept it as answer, so that others may know as well. thanks